# How would you make a javascript bookmarklet that sends all the markup of the page to a server?

Tags: javascript

How would one make a javascript bookmarklet that transmitted all the content of the page (including HTML tags) to a server other than the one the page was served from?

I don't necessarily need all the code, just some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it would be a *long* bookmarklet, but you could *get* the text with

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

and you could post it somewhere it XHR (or by creating a form and posting that).

Comment: Simpler: `document.documentElement.innerHTML`